# How to migrate a Spring MVC project with JSP and JQuery from Bootstrap 3 to 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to migrate my Project with Jquery and JSP from Bootstrap 3 to 4.

I have downloaded the bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css and popper.min.js files from Boostrap CDN and placed it in my JS folder. The website styles and alignments have changed now and I want to update the styles in custom format.

But when I check in Browser console, I could see some of the formatting are referenced from .less and .scss files. How and where do I add these in my Project?

Comment: You should be migrating to 5. It's not that different from 4 and 4 is obsolete.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question is too broad.

Comment: I want to understand what to do with the .less files. Should I do something and convert it into .css files?

Comment: That depends on whether you're using a build process and/or need a custom package. You can simply load Bootstrap via CDN or load just the compiled CSS files. As I said, your question is too broad because we don't know enough about your situation. Please don't follow up with more comments. _Improve your question post._